# How can i use both function in one

Tags: php, wordpress-shortcode

I have two shortcodes which working well separately (WordPress)

`[str_replace(",", ".", {rating[1]})]` This one changing comma to dot

[`MATH({rating[1]},"*","20")]` Here i need rating change to dot from comma before multiply 20

I tried this but not working

```
[MATH(str_replace(",", ".", {rating[1]}),"*","20")]
```

Comment: did you try `[(str_replace(",", ".", MATH({rating[1]})),"*","20")]`?

Comment: check from here https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: @fmsthird When I use Your code i get error: Post content template is invalid: Unexpected token OPEN, statement was expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this [here's reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
[$svalue = str_replace(",", ".", {rating[1]});]
[MATH({$value},"*","20");]
```

Comment: Check the reference [short_code](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)     
 **// [bartag foo="foo-value"] function bartag_func( $atts ) { $a = shortcode_atts( array( 'foo' => 'something', 'bar' => 'something else', ), $atts ); return "foo = {$a['foo']}"; } add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );)**